# Извлечение постов по нескольким тегам

Tags: php, mysql, алгоритм

**Дано:** в БД типа mySQL есть 3 таблицы (перечислю только поля, имеющие отношение к вопросу):

1. `post (id)`
2. `tag (id, text)`
3. `tagpost (id, tagid, postid)`

Таблица `tag` содержит описание тега (слово и его идентификатор). При добавлении тега на пост, помещается запись в таблицу `tagpost` с идом тега и поста. В таблицу `tagpost` добавляется столько записей, сколько было добавлено тегов на этот пост.

**Нужно:** Юзер в интерфейсе указал выборку по двум тегам. Нужно извлечь посты, которые помечены *и тегом1 и тегом2*. Извлечь посты, помеченные *только одним* определенным тегом - не составляет труда (`inner join`), но как красиво решить задачу при нескольких тегах? Пусть не за 1 запрос, но чтобы в итоге быстро работало. А то на ум приходит только говнокод.
ps. Метку "php" в вопросе поставил, т.к. кодится на этом языке, вдруг понадобятся специфичные функции из него.

Comment: Вот здесь хорошо бы работала mongodb :)

Comment: Для двух тэгов есть частное решение. А что если будет два, три, пять тэгов? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самое простое - приджойнить теги два раза, сначала один, потом второй:

```
select p.* from post p 
    join tagpost tp1 on tp1.post=p.id join tag t1 on tp1.tag=t1.id 
    join tagpost tp2 on tp2.post=p.id join tag t2 on tp2.tag=t2.id 
    where t1.name='tag1' and t2.name='tag2';
```

Но для неизвестного количества тегов такой запрос без квери билдера строить будет неудобно и некрасиво. Более акуратный вариант:

```
select p.* from tagpost tp join tag t on tag=t.id 
    join post p on post = p.id where name in ('tag1','tag2') 
    group by post having count(1) = 2;
```

но здесь надо помнить, что запросы с `group by` сложнее в оптимизации.

Comment: Это же до меня дошло, сразу же после публикации вопроса (что называется, хорошая мысля приходит опосля). Только лучше юзать inner join.

Answer (score -1):

По-моему, так должно работать:

```
select p.id, p.name
from post p inner join tagpost tp on p.id = tp.postid
where t.tagid in (@tagid1, @tagid2)
group by p.id, p.name -- Всё что в select
having count(tp.tagid) = 2 -- Число тегов в списке
```

Любое количество тегов - число join'ов от этого не зависит.

Answer (score -2):

синтаксис MS SQL, но думаю и в MySQL должен отработать. Вместо IN можно подселект сделать и проверить по EXISTS:

```
select P.id, P.tagid, P.postid 
FROM tagpost as P INNER JOIN tag T ON P.tagid = T.id
WHERE T.text IN('tag1', 'tag2')
```

Comment: извлечется или тот или другой, но не по двоим сразу

Comment: оба будут в выборке, можете проверить

Comment: Этот код выберет tag1 или tag2, а надо tag1 **И** tag2 (у статьи два этих тэга сразу, но не один из них)

Comment: на MSSQL можно так: declare @t table(id int, tag varchar(10))

insert into @t (id, tag)
values (1, 'tag1'), (2, 'tag2'), (3, 'tag3'), (4, 'tag4'), (5, 'tag5'), (6, 'tag6')


select * from @t t1 cross join @t t2 where t1.tag = 'tag1' and t2.tag = 'tag6'